# Заменить пустую ячеку excel по ряду условий

Tags: excel, условия, замена

Помогите пожалуйста.
Есть большая таблица (>3000 строк), надо проверить определенный столбец (F) на наличие пустых ячеек. Если такая(вые) имеются(F3), надо проверить значение в другой ячейке (A3)(артикулы), на совпадение с верхней или нижней строкой (A2, A4)(дубликат строки), в зависимости от совпадения (к примеру дубликат оказался сверху A2), вытащить значение из ячейки в этой строке (F2) и вставить в пустую (F3).
Строки дубликаты (из которых взяли значение (строка 2)) удалить.

есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании формулы на ячейку:

```
= IF (F3 = "";
    IF (A3 = A2; F2;
        IF(A3 = A4; F4)
    ); ""
)
```

получаю ошибку (err 511), т.к. при заполнении данными, она перестает быть пустой. Соответственно условие меняется.
Я видимо что то мудрю...

Comment: Формулу писать в свободный столбец, не в `F`: `= IF(F3="";IF(A3 = A2; F2;IF(A3=A4;F4;""));F3)` Дубликаты строк формула, естественно, не удалит. === Вопрос: рядом расположены 2 строки, из которых взяты значения - как удалять? Например. В `F3` вставили значение из `А2`, в `F4` вставили значение из `А3`. Т.е. строка 3 в этом случае и донор (такую нужно удалить), и акцептор (как бы, нужно оставить).

Comment: Я как понимаю, надо создать новый столбец для формулы. (была такая идея) Она так же не работает. При заполнении пустой ячейки в колонке F, формула тут же выдаёт ошибку, т.к. данная ячейка более не пустая. Я как понимаю формулы в excel работают в постоянном парсинге. Данная идея сработает, если результат формулы так же записать в новый столбец. Потом из этого столбца скопировать значения. Заменить в колонке F.

Comment: Формулу подправленную показал. А по решению - да: формула в доп. столбце, потом формула заменяется на значение, исходный столбец удаляется (или в нем заменяются данные). Но перед удалением столбца надо отметить строки, которые тоже под удаление. Это можно сделать с помощью формулы, но Вы не ответили на вопрос из сообщения выше.

Comment: Да, через три действия (формула - копирование значений - удаление строк) работает, но конечно не продуктивно. Быстрее получилось через сводные таблицы. В любом случае спасибо за помощь.